# How do I call NSViewController from NSAppDelegate's openFiles:(NSArray<NSString *> *)filenames method?

Tags: objective-c, macos

In my OS X app, I am opening the configuration view controller by storyboard. Now, when my

```
-(void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray<NSString *> *)filenames
```

method gets called, I want to change my NSViewController, but how? In iOS, I can change it by rootViewController, but I'm not sure about OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I know there might be a better solution but I used the following solution for my problem:

- I created app as document based Mac app.
- Instead of two view controllers, I took two window controllers.
- As per requirement I call following method for opening required view controller.

  ```
      [[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow:[myWindowController window]];
  ```

If this is wrong or if have any other solution plz let me know.